# error encountered while installing zend server

Tags: zend, zendframework

Got the following error while installing zend server
    Errors were encountered while processing:
    libapache2-mod-php-5.5-zend-server
    zend-server-php-5.5
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I tried `sudo ./installzend_zs.sh 5.5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution:

The php is already installed

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get remove php did worked for me